# One-to-many relationship Hibernate Problem

Tags: hibernate

I'm having Spring intergrate Hibernate project.But I add one-to-many in project I got error

My SQL Script:

```
create table users(
  username varchar(50) not null primary key,
  password varchar(50) not null,
  enabled boolean not null
  );

create table authorities (
  username varchar(50) not null,
  authority varchar(50) not null,
  constraint fk_authorities_users foreign key(username)references users(username));
```

UserVO class map table User

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="users",schema="public")
public class UserVO implements UserDetails,Serializable{

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private String username;
 private String password;
 private boolean enabled;

 private Set<AuthorityVO>authorityList = new HashSet<AuthorityVO>();

 @Id
 @Column(name="username",length=50,nullable=false)
 @Override
 public String getUsername() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return username;
 }

 public void setUsername(String username) {
  this.username = username;
 }

 @Column(name="password",length=50,nullable=false)
 @Override
 public String getPassword() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return password;
 }

 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }

 @Column(name="enabled",nullable=false)
 @Override
 public boolean isEnabled() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return enabled;
 }


 public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
  this.enabled = enabled;
 }


 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
 public Set<AuthorityVO> getAuthorityList() {
  return authorityList;
 }

 public void setAuthorityList(Set<AuthorityVO> authorityList) {
  this.authorityList = authorityList;
 }

 @Transient
 @Override
 public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  return null;
 }

 @Transient
 @Override
 public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }
 @Transient
 @Override
 public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }

 @Transient
 @Override
 public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }
}
```

AuthorityVO class map table authorities

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="authorities",schema="public")
public class AuthorityVO {

 private UserVO user;
 private String authority;

 @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name="username",nullable=false)
 @ForeignKey(name="fk_authorities_users")
 public UserVO getUser() {
  return user;
 }

 public void setUser(UserVO user) {
  this.user = user;
 }


 @Column(name="authority",length = 50,nullable=false)
 public String getAuthority() {
  return authority;
 }

 public void setAuthority(String authority) {
  this.authority = authority;
 }
```

At first I didn't add @OneToMany in UserVO and not AuthorityVO,All was fine.But i add those things to my project I got error

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.vaannila.vo.AuthorityVO
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
```

I know error means AuthorityVO not true map with Table authorities.But I find a lot of web and ebooks but I cannnot find where is problem to fix.Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your entity AuthorityVO has no primary key (database) and there fore also no ID-Column (annotated with @Id) in hibernate.

Further more it is better to use always some numeric primary keys in a good database design and a semantic column as you did with UserVO.

Comment: Thanks lweller.It works fine.I now know that 1 entity map in Hibernate must has @Id.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.vaannila.vo.AuthorityVO

it's mean you are not have any primary key for AuthorityVO class in database 
and no ID column like @id map with database.
So Hibernate can not find any identifier( unique column that is use to differtiate b/w objects and use to fetch objects from database ) for AuthorityVO  class.